# How to include additional items in the project

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, force.com

I use Eclipse with Salesforce plugin to access my Salesforce ORG. I have generated a project and can see a bunch of items like classes, triggers, pages etc. However when I first generated the project I have skipped reports. 
Is there a way to include additional items in the already generated roject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Steps

- In the Package Explorer, right-click your project and choose
  Properties.
- In the Project Properties dialog, expand the Force.com
  node and click Project Contents.
- On the Project Contents page, click Add/Remove Metadata Components.
- Use the Choose Metadata Components dialog to add / remove the component.
- In the Package Explorer, expand the nodes to find the component you want to add/remove.

For details
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_projects_delete.htm

Comment: Thank you! I was confused between Project Explorer and Package Explorer